# when do we change the adjective form depending on nouns?

Tags: meaning

I thought I know about changing in adjective forms depending on Nouns. However, I started to get confused again

"Meinst du, Ich kann mein Portemonnaie kriegen?"

Here, what is the difference between "mein" and "meines"
I thought it has to be meines here,
because there is no ein or das in front of Noun..

So, what I am curious of is, when do we use mein + neuter nouns in sentences?

Comment: Technically the question above is about masculine posessions, but it works the same for neutral ones (only females are different).

Comment: I do not see why this is supposed to be a duplicate. The current question is about *neuter* gender and *accusative* case. The alleged duplicate was about *masculine* gender and *nominative* case, and in addition it was based on an erroneous reference.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that [*mein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein#mein_(Deutsch)) is not an adjective but a posessive pronoun, namely of the first person singular.

The inflection of the posessive pronoun basically depends on whether it is used attributively (before a noun) or not.

> Meinst du, ich kann *mein* Portemonnaie kriegen?

Here, *mein* is apparently used attributively, as it precedes the neuter noun *Portemonnaie*. It is in accusative case.

For completenes, the following table lists the inflections for the *neuter* gender and for each case (N: nominative, G: genitive, D: dative, A: accusative), when used attributively versus when used non-attributively. The **bolded** item is the one used in the example sentence.

**Attributively – non-attributively (*neuter* gender)**

- N: mein – meines
- G: meines – meines
- D: meinem – meinem
- A: **mein** – meines

A similar example with non-attributive usage of *mein* is:

> Unsere Portemonnaies wurden geklaut. Meinst du, ich kann *meines* wiederkriegen?